# How can I generate a QR code without white space around it using the QrCode.net library?

Tags: c#, .net, qr-code

```
    using Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding;
    using Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding.Windows.Controls;

    private QrEncoder Encoder = new QrEncoder(ErrorCorrectionLevel.H);
    private Renderer renderer = new Renderer(15);

    BitMatrix qr = Encoder.Encode("12345").Matrix;
    Size size = Renderer.Measure(qr.Width);

    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Width);
    try
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        renderer.Draw(graphics,qr);
        return result;
    }
    catch
    {
        result.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
```

I can successfully generate QR codes with what I've got above. However, It always makes them with whitespace on all sides of the code. Is there an easy way to remove the whitespace, or, even better, generate the codes without it?

Comment: I assume you are aware that the white area around the QR code is technically part of the code (the "quiet zone") and that removing it may cause issues with regards successful identification and reading of the code by a reader?

Answer (score 0):

If library is not supporting it directly then you can always add one more step to crop the result bitmap.

```
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    renderer.Draw(graphics,qr);

Rectangle cropRectangle = Rectangle(
    borderWidth,borderHeight,result.Width-borderWidth, 
    result.Height-borderHeight);    
return result.Clone(cropRectangle, bmp.PixelFormat);
```